# JQuery Flexigrid question

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, jquery

Anyone know how to format the columns on a flexigrid?

http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/ToscaWidgets/Cookbook/FlexiGrid.html

the colModel doesn't seen to have any formatting params

I want to do simple things like format my date col with "{0:dd MMM yyyy}"

Answer (score 3):

Set the **process** property of the column you want to format, like this:

```
colModel: [
                {display: "ID", name: "id", width: 40, sortable: true, align: "center", process: procMe},
                {display: "Title", name: "title", width: 180, sortable: true, align: "left"}
              ],
```

notice the **process: procMe** on the first col, and then:

```
function procMe(celDiv,id) { 
   $(celDiv).html("Some formated text/icons/pics or whatever here");
};
```

I don't have a way to try it right now but i think it should work, sorry if there are any mistakes i just wrote it from memory and i might have forgotten something.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think flexigrid includes formatting properties.

Can't you format the date when you are fetching the data from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ToRrEs - format your data before you serialize it.  This way you push down just what you need to the client.

Comment: that's bad suggestion, because data should not depend on representation (frontend). If you use same data in 2 tables, that should be different, than you will need 2 different functions to get same data.